# How to get index of match element using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to get indexing of match element only. Like I have '.get' class in few TR. I want to get indexing based on '.get' class for instance. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TS477/)

```
.get 0
.get 1
.get 2


<table>
    <tr class="get"><td>view</td></tr>   
    <tr><td>view</td></tr>   
    <tr class="get"><td>view</td></tr>   
    <tr><td>view</td></tr>   
    <tr><td>view</td></tr>   
    <tr><td>view</td></tr>   
    <tr class="get"><td>view</td></tr>   
</table>

$('tr.get').click(function(){
    alert($(this,'.get').index())
})
```

Comment: Your fiddle is empty :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**.index( element )**](http://api.jquery.com/index/#index-selector)

> If a selector string is passed as an argument, .index() returns an integer indicating the position of the first element within the jQuery object relative to the elements matched by the selector.

Use

```
$('.get').index(this);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rupnu/)

Comment: Thanks, Exactly what I want

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can directly attach the index in the handler. It will fail if you have dynamic data, but it will be much faster if you have a lot of data since it does not recompute the index each time.

```
$('.get').each(function(index) {
    $(this).click(function() {
        alert(index);
    })
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/g5YMH/)

Answer (score 0):

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wEjtL/)

**JS**

```
$('.get').click(function () {
    alert($(this, '.get').index())
})
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr class="get">
        <td>view</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>view</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="get">
        <td>view</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>view</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>view</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>view</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="get">
        <td>view</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```